# Google Assistant on iPhone 7 shows no microphone or keyboard

Tags: iphone, google-assistant

On my iPhone 7 OS 14.3 Google Assistant app shows no microphone or keyboard leaving me without the ability to do much. How can I activate the mic and/or keyboard? Microphone is enabled in Privacy and in Settings->Assistant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure:
Your Google Nest or Home speaker or display is powered on and plugged into a wall outlet.
The microphone isn't muted.
For Google Home: On the back of the device, touch the microphone mute button. Your Assistant will say whether the microphone is muted.
For Google Nest Mini (2nd gen) and Google Home Mini (1st gen): On the side of the device, toggle the mic switch. Your Assistant will say whether the microphone is muted.
For Google Nest Audio: On the back of the device, next to the power cord, toggle the mic switch. Your Assistant will say whether the microphone is muted.
For Google Nest displays: On the back of your display, use the switch to turn on the microphone. Your Assistant will say whether the microphone is muted.
The LED dots on top of your speaker or display will spin or blink when you say “Ok Google” or "Hey Google."
If your Assistant answers other questions, try to ask the unanswered question in a different way.
General troubleshooting
If you've checked off all of the steps above and your Assistant still doesn't provide an answer, try one of the steps below and ask your question again. If you still don't get an answer, move to the next step.

Step 1. Reboot your speaker or display
Disconnect the power cable from your device.
Reconnect the power cable.
Step 2. Make sure your device recognizes the hotword
Say “Hey Google” to your speaker or display. Check if the LED dots on the top of your device spin or blink, indicating that it recognized the hotword.

Step 3. Make sure your device recognized the question correctly
Ask your Assistant the question again.
Say "Hey Google, repeat the question" to make sure your Assistant understood you correctly.
If it's still not recognizing the question, try to speak slower or try another question.
Step 4. Adjust the hotword sensitivity of your device
If your speaker or display often has trouble activating when you say “Hey Google” or "Ok Google,” you can adjust how sensitive Google Assistant is to “Hey Google.”

Advanced troubleshooting
If your Assistant still can't answer the question, submit a feedback report from the Google Home app.

OS 14.4 already exit. You can update! If dont help reset to factory! It may help you.

Comment: Actually after updating OS 14.4 I do see the mic and keyboard actions. Nice. Thanks @bigua